# Aloe ID and why they look stunted?

Tags: identification, watering, succulents, growth, aloe

My Aloes are growing well. Those two, however seem to prefer different conditions. I never figured-out if they do better with more shade (leaves become more succulent but much paler), or more water (Not much change). In either case they either retain the top leaves only, or remain full of curled "dry" leaves, like the one in the first picture. Extra watering does not help either. The leaves are widely spaced but this may be their natural growth pattern. As I have no ID, I could not find a reference picture on how a collector's item should look like.

I took cuttings several times. They root and grow, but slowly and have the same problem.
What is so different with those Aloes? Are they naturally so (then nothing I can do), or am I providing the wrong temperature, lighting and watering regime?
[image: Aloe-1]
[image: Aloe-2]